# Using str in split in pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, split

Here is some dummy data I have created for my question. I have two questions regarding this:

1. Why is `split` working by using `str` in the first part of the query and not in the second part?
2. How come `[0]` is picking up the first row in part 1 and the first element from each row in part 2?

```
chess_data = pd.DataFrame({"winner": ['A:1','A:2','A:3','A:4','B:1','B:2']})

chess_data.winner.str.split(":")[0]
['A', '1']

chess_data.winner.map(lambda n: n.split(":")[0])
0    A
1    A
2    A
3    A
4    B
5    B
Name: winner, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- `chess_data` is a dataframe
- `chess_data.winner` is a series
- `chess_data.winner.str` is an accessor to methods that are string specific and optimized (to a degree)
- `chess_data.winner.str.split` is one such method
- `chess_data.winner.map` is a different method that takes a dictionary or a callable object and either calls that callable with each element in the series **or** calls the dictionaries `get` method on each element of the series.

In the case of using `chess_data.winner.str.split` Pandas does do a loop and performs a kind of `str.split`.  While `map` is a more crude way of doing the same thing.

---

With your data.

```
chess_data.winner.str.split(':')

0    [A, 1]
1    [A, 2]
2    [A, 3]
3    [A, 4]
4    [B, 1]
5    [B, 2]
Name: winner, dtype: object
```

In order to get each first element, you'll want to use the string accessor again

```
chess_data.winner.str.split(':').str[0]

0    A
1    A
2    A
3    A
4    B
5    B
Name: winner, dtype: object
```

This is the equivalent way of performing what you had done in your `map`

```
chess_data.winner.map(lambda x: x.split(':')[0])
```

---

You could have also used a comprehension

```
chess_data.assign(new_col=[x.split(':')[0] for x in chess_data.winner])

  winner new_col
0    A:1       A
1    A:2       A
2    A:3       A
3    A:4       A
4    B:1       B
5    B:2       B
```

Answer (score 6):

Your code,

```
chess_data['winner'].str.split(':')[0] 
['A', '1']
```

Is the same as,

```
chess_data['winner'].str.split(':').loc[0] 
['A', '1']
```

And,

```
chess_data['winner'].map(lambda n: n.split(':')[0])
0    A
1    A
2    A
3    A
4    B
5    B
Name: winner, dtype: object
```

Is the same as,

```
chess_data.winner.str.split(':').str[0]
0    A
1    A
2    A
3    A
4    B
5    B
Name: winner, dtype: object
```

Which is also the same as,

```
pd.Series([x.split(':')[0] for x in chess_data['winner']], name='winner') 
0    A
1    A
2    A
3    A
4    B
5    B
Name: winner, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 5):

It is explained in the documentation under [Indexing using str](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str)

.str[index] notation indexes the string by position where as [index] will slice based on the index of the series.

Using the example

```
s = pd.Series(['A', 'B', 'C', 'Aaba', 'Baca', np.nan,'CABA', 'dog', 'cat'])

s.str[3]
```

returns the element at index 3 at each row

```
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    NaN
3      a
4      a
5    NaN
6      A
7    NaN
8    NaN
```

Whereas

```
s[3]
```

returns

```
'Aaba'
```

Answer (score 3):

Use apply method to extract first value from the splitted Series

```py
chess_data.winner.str.split(':')
Out: 
0    [A, 1]
1    [A, 2]
2    [A, 3]
3    [A, 4]
4    [B, 1]
5    [B, 2]
Name: winner, dtype: object

chess_data.winner.str.split(':').apply(lambda x: x[0])
Out:
0    A
1    A
2    A
3    A
4    B
5    B
Name: winner, dtype: object
```

When you use

```py
chess_data.winner.str.split(":")[0]
```

you just get fist item from the resulting series. But .apply() *applies* some function, in this case, 'itemgetter', to all the values in the series and returns another series.