# Why does .apply(lambda x: x[index]) give 'TypeError' on a column with string?

Tags: python, pandas, string

I have the following column in a dataframe

```
    Cabin
0   B/0/P
1   F/0/S
2   A/0/S
3   A/0/S
4   F/1/S
```

I want to change the column so that it shows only the last letter, either 'P' or 'S'.

I tried the following code:

```
df['Cabin'] = df['Cabin'].apply(lambda x: x[-1])
```

But this gives me

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

Then I tried this code and it works.

```
df['Cabin'] = df['Cabin'].apply(lambda x: str(x)[-1])
```

Why do I need to convert x to string when the rows in df['Cabin'] are already string?

If I try `type(df['Cabin'][0])` it returns 'str'. So, why does it become 'float' in the error above?

Comment: try, ``df['Cabin'].str.split('/').str[-1]`` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using str in split in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51911933/using-str-in-split-in-pandas)

Comment: No. I'm curious about why the x in lambda isn't recognised as str when it's already str.

Comment: @EddieStan I cannot reproduce your error. When I have `df = pd.DataFrame({'Cabin': ['B/0/P','F/0/S']})` and then run `df['Cabin'] = df['Cabin'].apply(lambda x: x[-1])`, I get the expected output. What does `df.dtypes` return, and what version of pandas are you using?

Comment: I figured it out. I forgot to account for the missing values in the column, NaN values are float which is why it gives the error.

Answer (score 0):

When working with heterogeneous data, the dtype of the resulting ndarray will be chosen to accommodate all of the data involved. For example, if strings are involved, the result will be of object dtype. If there are only floats and integers, the resulting array will be of float dtype.

Since a float series can accommodate NaN and int values, while an STR series cannot accommodate NaN, your series will have dtype float.

Reference: @**jon-clements**